I need to convert vertical text to horizontal line and add an "or"after each entry
$ cat myfile
servera
serverb
serverc

All in a vertical line. I need to convert it to horizontal line and add an "or"after each server.  to look like
servera or serverb or serverc 

I have tried tr command,
tr '\n' ' ' <myfile
servera serverb serverc  

I need help to add "or" in between the names:
I want to look like:
servera or serverb or serverc  


please update the question to include your coding attempt(s) and the (wrong) output generated by said code

And also, what do you mean by "I have". You have a text file containing those lines? A command that produces them? A variable? Etc.

$ cat myfile
servera
serverb
serverc
$ tr '\n' ' ' <myfile
servera serverb serverc
Please help me modify the tr  (or use vi or sed) to add "or" between words:
servera or serverb or serverc

The following worked, thanks everyone.
If you can think of any other solutions, that would be great.
perl -pe 's/\n/ or / unless eof' myfile
